# What's the procedure to stream a libuvc code in a gtk window?

Tags: c, image, gtk, libusb, uvc

Im currently working on linux. Im given a task to code in C using libuvc to stream a video from a USB camera to the window using GTK. I'm getting the out from the uvc_frame_t but I have a problem in streaming it in gtk window. Can someone help?

Comment: What problem do you have? What doesn't work? What have you tried? Show code.

Comment: I tried getting the frame in rgb by "uvc_any2rgb(frame,rgb);". Basically this rgb has the image data from the camera. How do I map it into the gtk window? Should I use GdkPixbuf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-Image-Data-in-Memory.html#gdk-pixbuf-new-from-data) to convert the data from `uvc_any2rgb` into a `GdkPixbuf`. A basic GTK UI would be a `GtkWindow` with a `GtkImage` in it.

To update the image, call `gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf` with a fresh new pixbuf you created. Don't forget to either reuse the pixbuf or destroy it after use, otherwise you'll face some massive memory leak. Oh, and you'll have to handle the framerate by yourself, and use a GLib event source to be notified when a new image is available from `libuvc`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and another thing is, since uvc_start_streaming() involves a callback function, Should I need to write all this in that?